# HTML/CSS Stretch anchor in div

Tags: html, css, anchor

I have the [following code](http://www.cssdesk.com/AwaaB) and want the anchor everywhere in the box not only at the image:

HTML:

```
<p style="clear:left" />
<div class="reference_container">
      <div class="reference_box reference_box_geraete">
      <a href="google.de">
        <img src="http://www.hanselman.com/blog/content/binary/WindowsLiveWriter/Hans.NETMVCJeffAtwoodandhistechnicalteam_1349C/stackoverflow-logo-250_3.png"/>
      </a>
      </div>
      <div class="reference_box reference_box_geraete">
      <a href="google.de">
        <img src="http://www.johndscomputers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/200px-Apple_logo_black.svg_.png"/>
      </a>
      </div>
      <div class="reference_box reference_box_geraete">
      <a href="google.de">
        <img src="http://www.johndscomputers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/200px-Apple_logo_black.svg_.png"/>
      </a>
      </div>
      <div class="reference_box reference_box_geraete">
      <a href="google.de">
        <img src="http://www.hanselman.com/blog/content/binary/WindowsLiveWriter/Hans.NETMVCJeffAtwoodandhistechnicalteam_1349C/stackoverflow-logo-250_3.png"/>
      </a>
      </div>
</div>
<p style="clear:left" />
```

CSS:

```
.reference_container {
  display: flex;
}

.reference_box {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 1%;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
}

.reference_box_geraete {
  width: 22%;
  /*box-sizing: border-box;*/
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.reference_box_geraete img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

The problem is that I don't get the anchor to stretch to the whole surrounding div.
I tried to remove the div and make the anchor as block-element, but then the images are not stretched correctly (doesn't keep aspect-ratio) when resizing the browser window.

How can I achieve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: can you describe your situation a little bit better, and post the specific css class that is giving you problems here (thanks for doing up the demo but I don't quite understand what you're looking for)

Comment: I hope it's better to understand now. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

set width , height and `display:block` for element a

Answer (score 0):

check this:

```
<p style="clear:left" />
<div class="reference_container">
      <a  class="reference_box reference_box_geraete" href="google.de">
        <img src="http://www.hanselman.com/blog/content/binary/WindowsLiveWriter/Hans.NETMVCJeffAtwoodandhistechnicalteam_1349C/stackoverflow-logo-250_3.png"/>
      </a>
      <a href="google.de" class="reference_box reference_box_geraete">

        <img src="http://www.johndscomputers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/200px-Apple_logo_black.svg_.png"/>
      </a>

      <a href="google.de" class="reference_box reference_box_geraete">

        <img src="http://www.johndscomputers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/200px-Apple_logo_black.svg_.png"/>
      </a>

      <a href="google.de" class="reference_box reference_box_geraete">

        <img src="http://www.hanselman.com/blog/content/binary/WindowsLiveWriter/Hans.NETMVCJeffAtwoodandhistechnicalteam_1349C/stackoverflow-logo-250_3.png"/>
      </a>

</div>
<p style="clear:left" />
```

Demo: http://www.cssdesk.com/p5Cqd

Comment: This solution has problems when resizing the window, because the aspect-ratio of the image isn't preserved.